# Как программно изменить иконку пункта меню (MenuItem)?

Tags: java, android, activity, android-toolbar, android-menu

У меня есть метод где инициализируется кастомный Toolbar к которому я прикрепил Меню. Мне надо из другого метода изменить иконки для пунктов меню. Как к ним доступиться?

```
public void initToolbar() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.refresh:

                    return true;
                case R.id.back:

                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_toolbar);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Вбиваем в гугл строку:

> [android change menu icon programmatically](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20change%20menu%20icon%20programmatically)

2. Идём по первой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19882443/3212712)
3. Получаем [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19882555/3212712):

создаём переменную в классе активити

```
private Menu menu;
```

В методе активити onCreateOptionsMenu() инициализируем её

```
this.menu = menu;
```

Далее в нужном месте находим нужный пункт и меняем иконку:

```
menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
```

Answer (score 1):

Я делаю так: заведите локальную переменную `private Menu menu`. Потом делайте следующее:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        this.menu = menu;
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_news, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

После чего этим методом можно менять иконки:

```
private void updateMenuIcons() {
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.icon);
        menuItem.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    }
```

Незнаю насколько это корректно, но для меня работает.

Comment: я уже пробовал так, в строчке MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.icon); выкидывает нал поинтер

Comment: под дебагом посмотрите, что первое происходит: инициализация тулбара или onCreateOptionsMenu?

Comment: Уже разобрался, у меня нет меню как такового, у меня есть только ToolBar в который я поместил пункты меню. Доставать Menu и MenuItem надо было именно из ToolBar.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить доступ к меню, которое находится в `ToolBar`, надо использовать метод `getMenu()` именно у `ToolBar`, а потом уже искать по ID пункт меню.

```
toolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.refresh).setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_back);
```